# Truncating titles (in a different language) in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, utf-8, truncate

I'm trying to truncate post titles that displaying on the home page's different kinds of widget boxes by using the following method:

I've inserted this into theme-functions.php

```
function customTitle($limit) {
    $title = get_the_title($post->ID);
    if(strlen($title) > $limit) {
        $title = substr($title, 0, $limit) . '...';
    }

    echo $title;
}
```

Then I can replace whatever titles I want with the following code:

```
<?php customTitle(30); ?>
```

It's working mostly fine except the website language is Simplified Chinese and apparently this truncate method doesn't compatible with the language (I'm guessing it's because the php is set in utf-8), it does truncate the title but it leaves an ugly question mark at the end of each title.

I'm wondering if someone can help me to change this code I used so it can compatible with utf8 and Chinese, or if there's any other better solutions?

Comment: Tried with mb_strlen? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use mb_substr to get a substring by characters (instead of bytes). This way you won't get broken characters at the end, but you may still get incomplete characters if the text uses combining marks or similar. https://www.php.net/mb_substr

Comment: Thanks, seems like this solution fits what I need, actually I'm not familiar with PHP so I took a wild guess by replacing 'substr' with 'mb_substr' in my code, and the questions marks are gone. The only down side is it seems adding '...' on all the titles, but I can live with that.